# How to find IIS7 SiteID using site name on Windows 2008 using appcmd or other util?

Tags: iis-7, appcmd

I am trying to find an IIS7 site ID using site name using `appcmd` or other utility but have not found any way to achieve it.

Comment: For those of us who likes the GUI utils - The IIS manager - Advanced settings - ID

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following command returns site ID:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD list site <SiteName>
```

Example output:

```
SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:default.local,state:Started)
SITE "My Site" (id:2,bindings:http/*:80:my.local,state:Started)
```

Comment: You can get a specific property of the Site (id, bindings, state) by using the /text:{property} argument.

For example, to get just the ID (returns simply "1"):

    APPCMD list site "Default Web Site" \text:id

Comment: this worked for me on iis 6, with the only exception being that I had to run the command prompt as an administrator

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is to load up IIS Manager and click on the "Sites" folder.  There should be a column called "ID" in the list shown in the Features View pane, and that's your Site ID.

Comment: Dave - This is certainly the easiest and instant display of the site ID right in front of us when the "Sites" main folder is clicked :) Excellent.

Answer (score 5):

You may also give a try to Powershell `get-website` commandlet. Without args it will list all sites together with IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Powershell-way of doing it:

```
Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site" | Select -ExpandProperty ID
```

(Replace Default Web Site with your site's name.)

Answer (score 1):

Save this a XXX.VBS

```
dim lookfor: lookfor = lcase(WScript.Arguments(0))
dim ws: set ws = getobject("IIS://localhost/w3svc")
for each site in ws
    if site.class = "IIsWebServer" then
        if lcase(site.ServerComment) = lookfor then
            wscript.echo "id=" & site.Name & ", name=" & site.ServerComment
        end if
    end if
next
```

then from the command line

```
XXX.vbs site.tofind.com
```

or

```
cscript XXX.vbs site.tofind.com
```